# Keep getting NameError from class variable?

Tags: python, function, class, methods

So I'm trying to fully understand Python OOP by creating a class but I'm really confused about this error I keep getting. Still learning so please try to understand my beginner situation here.

```
  class Investor:

    def __init__(self, name, principle, returns):
        self.name = name
        self.principle = principle
        self.returns = returns 

    def info(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.principle)

    def deposit(self):
        global deposit_amount

        deposit_amount = float(input('Amount: '))
        return deposit_amount + self.principle + self.returns

    def withdraw(self):
        global withdraw_amount

        withdraw_amount = float(input('Withdraw amount: '))
        return self.principle + self.returns + deposit_amount - withdraw_amount

    def balance(self):
        if deposit_amount > 0 or withdraw_amount > 0:
            return self.principle + self.returns + deposit_amount - withdraw_amount
        else:
            return self.principle + self.returns



    


investor1 = Investor('John', 5000, 0)

while True:
    prompt = input('What would you like to do?\n')
    if prompt == 'Balance':
        try:
            print(investor1.balance())
        except ValueError:
            print(investor1.info())


    elif prompt == 'Deposit':
        print(investor1.deposit())

    elif prompt == 'Withdraw':
        print(investor1.withdraw())
```

Output:

```
What would you like to do?
```

When I first enter `Deposit` and then `Withdraw` and ***then*** `Balance` the code works perfectly fine.

However, when I input `Balance` first, I get the following error:

```
return self.principle + self.returns + deposit_amount - withdraw_amount
NameError: name 'deposit_amount' is not defined
```

Any help, folks?

Comment: Creating global variables in your methods *completely misses the point* of using a class. The point is to encapsulate state, not use global state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `global deposit_amount` first when you call the `deposit(self)` method.
This statement puts the variable in the global scope. Before the call to  `deposit(self)` the variable is never defined, neither in the local function scope of `balance(self)` nor in the global scope. Therefore you get this error.
This has nothing to do with OOP python in the first places but is just a problem of scope.
To do this in a object oriented way I would suggest you put the variable as a class instance member:

```
def __init__(self, name, principle, returns):
    self.name = name
    self.principle = principle
    self.returns = returns
    self.deposit_amount = 0
    self.withdraw_amount = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you input `Balance` first, then neither `deposit_amount` nor `withdraw_amount` gets defined, both of which are needed for the `if` statement in the `balance` definition.

Answer (score 0):

The "deposit_amount" is a local variable of the function deposit. So unless you run the deposit fn. first, as far as the system is concerned doesn't exist. so try and initialize the same globally.
if you wanna read up on the local and global variables, refer to:
[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/global-and-local-variables-in-python#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20types%20of,function%20where%20it%20is%20defined](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/global-and-local-variables-in-python#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20types%20of,function%20where%20it%20is%20defined).

Answer (score 0):

The `deposit_amount` variable is unknown in function `withdraw` if you try to withdraw before depositing. You have to either add `global deposit_amount` and declare this variable somewhere but it's not in OOP style. The best thing to do is to add this variable to your `__init__` as `self.deposit_amount = 0`. And then reference it by `self` in all functions defined in class `Investor`.